# What is the point of using @Autowired with new keyword?

Tags: spring-boot

I inspect some autoconfiguration classes from Spring boot.
In `LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class` i noticed that LiquibaseProperties is autowired and at the same time created using `new` operator:

```
    @Autowired
    private LiquibaseProperties properties = new LiquibaseProperties();

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
```

This does not apply for all configuration classes, i also noticed this in `JooqAutoConfiguration`. Why `new` operator is used here?

Answer (score 3):

It's only really of any use with `@Autowired(required=false)`. In that case the instance that's been created by `new` would be used as a default value if an instance was not available for injection.

In the example you've shown an injected instance is always required so the instance created by`new` will either be replaced with injected instance or a failure will occur if there was no instance to inject. In short it's redundant and the code could have been written like this:

```
@Autowired
private LiquibaseProperties properties;

@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
```

Spring Boot 1.4 has fixed this by moving to constructor injection. Support for constructor injection in configuration classes was introduced in Spring Framework 4.3. The [code in question](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.java) now declares the fields as `final` and assigns their values in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about the construction of the object there is a period of time where that field would otherwise be null if the `new` operator was not used. I tried to find a diagram that showed the lifecycle of a managed bean but only found the documentation around the callbacks ([Spring Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-nature)).

Spring will normally instantiate the bean with the default constructor and do the "normal" things to the object (initialize fields). So in this case the fields get assigned new instances of the classes for those fields. Then Spring comes along and autowires the fields based on the instance of the class that is being managed within the ApplicationContext.

It does look odd but it may be due to some initialization within the class where a default properties and resource loader objects have to exist before Spring can do its autowiring?